# Conditional regex pattern for preg_match_all PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a pattern. Whenever a specific matching group is not present, it skips and find another match even if it skips the next matching group.

There are 4 capturing group.

first group, 2nd group, 3rd group, 4th group

3rd group is not always there. In my sample string, there are 3 sets. The first one does not contain any character for the 3rd group. I want a conditional statement for the 3rd group. If it does not found any character, then it should capture blank or space.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zK0aW4/1

it should be like this: https://regex101.com/r/sD4eB7/1

but I don't know how to assign condition for this.

If third match is not present then it should get blank. How do I write this in regex pattern?

For example:

```
$string = "\nTHIS IS FIRST PATTERN 63101 0789158126 0-0000000-000-0000\n4415 THIS IS FIRST \nPATTERN 49401-9528\n0406842931 Third match 0-0000000-000-0000\n11403 THIS IS FIRST PATTERN 49401-\n9595\n0112853789 Third match 0-0000000-000-0000";

preg_match_all(
    "/([A-Z ,\.\-\&#\\\\n\/0-9&amp;]+)(\d{10})([A-Z a-z]+)(\d{1}-\d{7}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{1}-\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4})/",
    $string,
    $matches
);
```

This should output something like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(78) "\nTHIS IS FIRST PATTERN 63101 0789158126 0-0000000-000-0000"
    [1]=>
    string(84) "\n4415 THIS IS FIRST \nPATTERN 49401-9528\n0406842931 Third match 0-0000000-000-0000"
    [2]=>
    string(87) "\n11403 THIS IS FIRST PATTERN 49401-\n9595\n0112853789 Third match 0-0000000-000-0000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "\nTHIS IS FIRST PATTERN 63101"
    [1]=>
    string(42) "\n4415 THIS IS FIRST \nPATTERN 49401-9528\n"
    [2]=>
    string(45) "\n11403 THIS IS FIRST PATTERN 49401-\n9595\n"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "0789158126"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "0406842931"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "0112853789"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) " "
    [1]=>
    string(15) " Third match "
    [2]=>
    string(15) " Third match "
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "0-0000000-000-0000"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "0-0000000-000-0000"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "0-0000000-000-0000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the first quantifier non-greedy: `+` => `+?`. For a more efficient pattern, you can also write it like this: https://regex101.com/r/zJ9rP2/1

Comment: This `&amp;` in a character class allows for each of those characters, not the entity. e.g. `&`, `a`, `m`, `p`, and `;`.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more sample input, expected matches, and tell us more clearly what is wrong with what you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/zK0aW4/2

```
((?:[A-Z ,.&#\/0-9-]|&amp;|\\n)+?)(\d{10})([A-Z a-z]+)?(\d{1}-\d{7}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{1}-\d{7}-\d{2}-\d{4})
```

Because your initial group has so many matches it was extending too far. By changing to a non-greedy or lazy match (`*?` or `+?`) it will match as little as possible. This makes it behave better with the following patterns.

Character classes (surrounded by `[` and `]`) are for matching single characters; I assumed that you wanted to match only a literal `&amp;` and `\n`, so moved those out of the character class.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I am looking for! I am new with regex pattern. Thank you for the info also.